# PhpStorm think that files created outside of it contain errors

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

For reasons discussed in another question, I have to create Laravel migrations in another project, then move them to the project I'm working on.

PhpStorm highlights the files in red and believes that they contain errors, how to fix that?

**Edit:**

Due to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217894/is-there-a-portable-php-artisan-tool), I wrote a batch script, it goes to some lumen project, generates the migration then sets the path to the work project

```
@ECHO off
doskey pa = D: $T cd D:\lumen $T php artisan make:migration $1 --path=../../work/database/migrations
```

PhpStorm cannot recognize the file generated

[image]

As you can see, a new migration, marked in red just because it was created somewhere else and moved to PhpStorm. It's not just migrations, if I create any PHP file using another editor and place it inside a PHPstorm project, it will be marked in red.

Comment: Please provide screenshots, especially of the error messages That's a minimum. Also describe what other stuff do you use (I mean -- Laravel helper package? Have you tried regenerating meta data etc). P.S. Quite possibly you would see the same if they would generated in the same project... If that is what I have seen in my projects.. it might be related to the namespace.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, I just did that. How to regenerate meta data?

Comment: Oh .. that one (file name in red). It has to be VCS status then; it's not Code Inspection as I initially thought. Check this and look further https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html#views

Comment: @LazyOne Can it be disabled?

Comment: Disabled what? Either disable VCS integration if you do not need it or  add those files to version control.